# Why python program runs with different result between Linux shell and Jenkins job

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have a python program, which should run in `Jenkins job`. But I got below error:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/automatic_test
[automatic_test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins257763233971180370.sh
+ cd /ext/data/nlu_test/ifly/job123
+ python3 bleu.py Zh ref_zh.txt translation_zh.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bleu.py", line 5, in <module>
    import jieba
ImportError: No module named 'jieba'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

While I run the same commands on `Linux shell`, then it runs normally as below. Why?

```
[jenkins@localhost ~]$ cd /ext/data/nlu_test/ifly/job123
[jenkins@localhost job123]$ ls
bleu.py  input.orig.txt  input.trans.txt  input.txt  ref_zh.txt  splitText.py  translation_zh.txt
[jenkins@localhost job123]$ python3 bleu.py Zh ref_zh.txt translation_zh.txt
W0310 00:06:37.430938 295363 init.cc:157] AVX is available, Please re-compile on local machine
Paddle enabled successfully......
reference 1: 3615
candidate: 3493
score: 31.8288254543782
[jenkins@localhost job123]$
```

And I installed the python package `jieba` already as below.

```
[root@localhost ~]# pip3 install jieba
Requirement already satisfied: jieba in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.42.1)
[root@localhost ~]# pip install jieba
Requirement already satisfied: jieba in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.42.1)
```

Comment: So.. did you install python package jieba on `[automatic_test] $`?

Comment: Tom: You can use absolute path for executing the script.
`Example: /usr/bin/python3 bleu.py Zh ref_zh.txt translation_zh.txt` 
Try once hope it helps :-)

Comment: @HussainK Thank you very much! It works now.

Comment: @KamilCuk Why should I install jieba on [automatic_test]? I am not familiar with Jenkins jobs.

Comment: Because I guess from `ImportError: No module named 'jieba'` you don't have it inside `[automatic_test]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute path of Python for executing the script in Jenkins.

```
Example: /usr/bin/python3 bleu.py Zh ref_zh.txt translation_zh.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check how your Jenkins agent is set up.  Usually, Jenkins agents run under a separate user ID than the one you are using.  This means that they use different environments than the one where you are doing your testing.  In your example, your python script fails to import a package.  You should see if this package exists and is available in the the environment used by the Jenkins agent.